# CodeIgniter 404 not page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm just learning CI, but I've encountered the following problem.
I created a controller home.php with class home (the size of letters is the same). The controller loads the view home_view.

In config.php, I have the following parameters:

```
config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./home.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Have you set the $config['base_url'] in config.php?

Comment: Yes, a set base_url.

Comment: I refactor a controller name, and class. First letter is uppercase - it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in your .htaccess file you redirect all callbacks to file home.php, instead of default CI's default index file, and this home.php does not exists (as you said it's a controller, and it should be in controllers folder)

htaccess should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This way, is index.php file from codeigniter who loads all requierd files (config, routes, etc) and calls the controller specified in config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

routes.php:

> $route['404_override'] = 'my404';

**Create a controller**
my404.php:

```
?php 
class my404 extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 

    public function index() 
    { 
       $this->load->view('error_404');//loading in my template 

    } 
} 
?>
```